Power efficient firmware update over USB between 2 pairs of STM32 chips
I have a very specific project and as I am new to using the USB features I am unsure what MCU to choose and how to design my USB port on my board. If possible I would like to use an STM32, simply because I am familiar with it.
I am developing a remote controller for some machine, where:

I need to have a main MCU and a supervisory MCU on both the remote and machine.
In case the battery on the remote dies, you should be able to power the remote to the machine.
The remote needs to be paired with the specific machine (where different machines may require different software to be used on the remote), so practically you would only update the firmware twice or maximum 3 times per remote if the machine was changed, but you always need to be able to power it.
The remote should have as small power consumption as possible to prolong battery life
Both remote and machine MCU should support 1x I2C, 3x UART (one of them can be switched to SPI)
(optional) The software on the machine side should never change, but you never know what errors you might encounter after testing the actual thing, so updating the machine MCU-s firmware over usb would also be nice.

So essentialy I need to be able to flash the two MCU-s on my remote from the two MCU-s on the machene side. The reason I want to do it over USB is, because we already need to be able to power the remote over a cable, so expanding it to also send the excecutable file seemed like a reasanoble choice, and it is  less power hungry than having an SD card in the remote to define, which software to use. USB was chosen simply because it is weidly used and alows data transfer and there are examples to update the firmware over it, not to mention that the final PCB would be compleatly blocked off except for the absolutely necessary acces points (one for batteries on the remote and one for USB on the remote and machine).

I have done quite a bit of research but as I don't really understand how USB works I am not really sure what MCU to choose or how to set up the communication.
I initially wanted to use some specific usb type (so the user won't try to connect it to PC, phone, brick...) and use its pins as SWD pins like in this example, where I only need to flash and I don't care about debugging. So if I understand correctly that would mean that my MCU on the remote would not have to support USB.
But then I am trying to update two MCU-s at the same time and most USB connectors have only 4 or 5 pins. So is it possible for all 4 MCU-s to share the SWCLK pin, where one of the controllers on the machine side would be setting it? Not to mention the pin that would put the remote MCU-s in to boot mode (altho I guess you could just be checking the activity on either SWCLK or SWDIO).
I could use USB-c, given that we are in modern times, but that would require the some extra protection on the pcb, since it is really easy for someone to stick the usb to somwhere they are not supposed to, resulting in some funny voltage, whereas with some USB type B for example, I make it a bit more mess up and stick a warning next to it and that would be that. I was looking at this USB-c example, without the need for the USB 2.0 functionality and by setting the right CC1 and CC2, pins so we know which pins are updating which MCU, but then this seems like an overkill, especially since we would only need a power supply between 2V and 5V (as the battery range is already between 2V and 4.5V).
And the only other option (please correct me if I am dreaming here) is to actually use the USB protocol, where I would need to have a low power MCU with at least USB device interface on the remote side and any MCU that supports USB host (or DRD if we want to also be able to update the machine firmware) on the machine side?
Do all of these options support supplying power or should I be looking at some specific combo? For example on the STM32 MCU selector there are a bunch of exlusive options:

Where power delivery is separate from USB 2, which I could technically also use to send data. And how do I set the protocol to update the right MCU with the right firmware?
Not to mention that people seem to avoid flashing over USB and usually go for some STLINK, for the initial flash, but I assumed that is only because most MCU-s don't support USB. There is also a concern that USB requires some drivers to start working, so what would happen if you unpluged the cable while the firmware only half updated? Do I need to keep another firmware backup somwhere if the update fails? That would mean that the MCU-s on the machine would need 3 whole firmwares in memory (1 in use, 1 as backup and 1 to flash the remote). Is there any other reason I shouldn't be doing this?
And lastly since I will always want to update 2 MCU-s at the same time, like this post mentiones, do I again need a cable that has enough pins, for multiple data transfers (so for example having multiple USB 2 pins configured on the USB cable, if that is even possible)? And can the communication be setup so that we can flash from MCU to MCU and not need some extra software like STM32cube programmer? One way around that is ofcourse to make use of SWD, but can the USB on the machine side act as a normal USB when connected to PC and as SWD pins when connected to the remote? It just seems to hacky to work.
So what is the best method to use or has anyone already tried some approach?

That's not a very specific question. But there's two problems, having 2 MCUs inside one box (why not use one big MCU, or one with enough safety features or one with dual core), and you simply having almost decided you want to use stadard USB connector for non-USB purposes. Larger MCUs have USB built in. Smaller MCUs don't. Some of them have factory bootloader to update over USB. Some have USB but require your custom bootloader on MCu to support USB update. You can use a USB to UART chip and update with a PC over MCU UART, usually a factory bootloader interface.

I'm not endorsing using a USB connector for non-USB purposes, but using a USB-C will not expose your device to 'some funny voltage'. Anything other than 5V needs to be explicitly requested by the device, so 5V is all you'd see.

Is this machine safety-related? In case you end up with safety-critical requirements (SIL etc) you'll want to use a functional safety MCU.

Also why would you ever want to update a new remote using old firmware stored on the machine...? Normally one only changes some configuration parameters in eeprom/data flash and code accordingly, rather than flashing the whole program. I think you should back away from the details and focus on the requirements - are they sound to begin with?

Yes it is a remote to controll a machine that requires ISO standards, and the main reason we were thinking of using 2 MCU is this:
"Category 3 requires that any single fault on an otherwise completely healthy system can not cause the failure of the safety function. This means there must be two separate signal paths (redundant wires, processors, pins on the EMS button and on the coil of valve in winch) for each safety function of category 3, in case one of the paths fails. Critical failure of safety function after accumulation of two or more errors is allowed"

And most, but not all other solutions used 2 MCU-s so it is not strictly asking us to use 2 chips and I guess there are other solutions like using one bigger MCU or simply using a different cable. But since flashing an MCU is in esence just sending an excecutable file, it felt like there should be an easy solution by using a USB for data transfer regardles of how many MCU-s we used.

The reason the idea for updating the firmware came up is, because there are cases where the user can change some feature on the machine (and with that they already have to change the chip that operates the while machine), so to avoid having to also change the whole remote, we could just update the firmware, since the controller itself shouldn't physicaly change. In the worst case you wold have to open up the housing and leave some swd pins, so this part is more of a it would be nice, but its not strictly a requierment.
